# I am using aria-live to announce a string. How do I make sure that the string is announced immediately before any other event announcement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aria-live

I am using aria-live to announce string. How to make sure that string is announced immediately before anything else is announced? The second part to the problem is that "aria-live announces only when text gets changed". How do I announce the same string repeatedly?

Comment: Please post your code snippets so other users can better help you

Answer (score 0):

To announce a string immediately, use **aria-live="assertive"**. "assertive" will announce the updates to the user as soon as possible. You can also use **aria-live="rude"** which will announce the updates straight away, even if this interrupts the user.